# Remove duplicate characters using AWK gsub()

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to reformat some text by removing newline and duplicated space characters.

My input text looks like this:

```
     hello  ! hello 
you! 

 hello



   world!!! hello


   universe  !
```

and I'm trying to format it like this:

```
hello !
hello you!
hello world!
hello universe !
```

I tried using this command:

```
awk -v RS='!' '{gsub("^ *|\n", ""); gsub(" +", " ")} NF{print $0 RS }' file
```

But I still get some spaces at the beginning of the line:

```
 hello !
hello you!
 hello world!
hello universe !
```

I don't understand why the first `gsub` is not removing the leading space (that should be matched by the pattern `^ *`).

What is wrong is this `awk` script?

I'm also interested in the `sed` command performing the same formatting.

Comment: It's because `^` means the beginning of a record and there is a newline between the space and hello, shouldn't have a space in front of the first line though. Use `[[:space:]]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='!' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/, ""); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")} NF{print $0 RS}' file
hello !
hello you!
hello world!
hello universe !
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='!'`

  This sets the record separator to an exclamation point.
- `gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/, "")`

  This removes all leading space.

  `[[:space:]]` is a unicode-safe way of matching any white space, which includes blanks, tabs, newlines, and some other more obscure white space.
- `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")`

  This replaces any other multiple space with a single blank
- `NF{print $0 RS }`

  If there are any words on this line, this prints them along with the record separator.

Comment: The `{print $0 RS }` is still needed  in order to get the `!` at the end. Anyway, your answer (with the `[[:space:]]`) is good. thanks.

Comment: maybe also update the output to match with the command (and add the 4 `!`).

Answer (score 1):

In sed

#### Cmdline

```
sed ':1;/!/!{$!{N;b1}};s/!\{2,\}/!/;s/\n*//g;s/^ *//;s/ \{1,\}/ /g;s/!/&\n/;/^$/d;P;D' file
```

#### Script

```
:1
/!/!{
        $!{
                N
                b1
        }
}
s/!\{2,\}/!/
s/\n*//g
s/^ *//
s/ \{1,\}/ /g
s/!/&\n/
/^$/d
P
D
```

Comment: Can you please give some explanation? BTW, there is an extra newline at the end of the output.

Comment: @oliv Blank lines will be deleted now, regarding explanation it's pretty self explanatory if you look at what each command does.

Comment: hmm... _self explanatory_ ... ok for the `s` substitution. The `/!/!` part is a mystery for me... same for the `P;D` command...

Comment: `/!/` matches a single `!` in pattern space, `!` negates this match, meaning if line does not contain `!`, execute the following block/command. `P` and `D` are documented in the man page.